# Multiple domains with unique DNS servers in resolv.conf

Tags: linux, networking, dns

I have the following `resolv.conf` for `example1.com` domain.

```
search example1.com
nameserver x.x.x.1
nameserver x.x.x.2
```

Now, I want to extend my `resolv.conf` to include `example2.com` as well. How do I write my `resolv.conf`?

After reading `resolv.conf` [manaual](https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf) page I came up with this:

```
search example1.com example2.com
nameserver x.x.x.1
nameserver x.x.x.2
nameserver x.x.x.3 # for example2.com
nameserver x.x.x.4 # for example2.com
```

I know that `example2.com` will be looked-up in the first two nameservers first and will timeout but when it reaches the third nameserver it should just work, shouldn't it?

Can someone shed some light on this please?

Comment: do you actually want the zone on the new servers? you could always carry that zone on the existing server (and even add the two new IPs if you like).  Do the example1 servers forward queries they can't answer? the example1 server should respond quickly with a NXDOMAIN response, rather than waiting for a timeout, but I don't believe it will retry with the next IP.  if would be best if you could either forward from the example1 server to external2, rather than trying to configure the client with multiple DNS servers that aren't carrying the same set of domains.

Comment: @FrankThomas Appreciate your comment as I have something to think over. Your point to forward from example1 to example2 is not possible in my case as of now.

Comment: are these resolvers or authorative servers? is the client you are connecting too supposed to be able to use the internet or query domains other than your examples 1 and 2?

Comment: It is an authoritative nameserver. No, it won't be able to query other domains. It is in a private network in cloud. I have resources (VMs) that needs to have this `resolv.conf`. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: sure. Typically a client would point to a resolver, but that's fine as long as you don't need to ever resolve other domains.

Answer (score 2):

The resolver library is designed on the assumption of a uniform DNS namespace.
Multiple nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` are only used for redundancy in case some of them are unreachable or otherwise unavailable.

Specifically, if the first consulted nameserver does not know a domain name it does *not* time out but return `NXDOMAIN` which means "this domain name does not exist." Consequently, the resolver will *not* contact the next nameserver in the list hoping for a different answer, but will accept that result and pass it on to the application which did the query.

What's more, there is no guarantee that the resolver library function will consult the nameservers in the order given in `/etc/resolv.conf`. It is free to reorder them for example according to the speed with which they answered in the past.

And finally, the `search` statement does not work the way you seem to assume.
It simply lists the domains that should be appended to a domain name that cannot be resolved as it is.

In sum, your proposed `resolv.conf` file

```
search example1.com example2.com
nameserver x.x.x.1
nameserver x.x.x.2
nameserver x.x.x.3
nameserver x.x.x.4
```

produces the following behaviour when an application tries to resolve a name `dst.host`:

1. Ask an arbitrary nameserver from the list `x.x.x.1`, `x.x.x.2`, `x.x.x.3`, `x.x.x.4` for the domain name `dst.host.`
2. If the request times out, continue asking the other nameservers from the list until one of them replies. If none of them replies, return an error to the application.
3. If the reply is *not* NXDOMAIN, return the found results to the application.
4. If the reply *is* NXDOMAIN, repeat step 1 to 3, this time asking for the domain name `dst.host.example1.com.`
5. If the reply is again NXDOMAIN, repeat step 1 to 3, this time asking for the domain name `dst.host.example2.com.`
6. If the reply is yet again NXDOMAIN, return result NXDOMAIN (not found) to the application.

If you have a split horizon situation where you need to query different nameservers for different domains then you need to employ a DNS proxy like `dnsmasq` which is able to forward queries to  different nameservers depending on their domains.

Comment: Looking at the behaviors you listed out, is it fair to say that it will still work but is inefficient and a `dnsmasq` is the right solution as I need to query different nameservers for different domains.

Comment: Actually no, it won't work. In each round through steps 1 to 3, there's a 50% probability that the query will be sent to the wrong server, and nothing in the process will detect and correct that. So it will randomly return the wrong result "not found" for a name that exists.